# Ansible aclling two diffrent file variables into single task looping through multiple files

Tags: linux, ansible

### Content of `fil1`

```
# cat file1
fostrain01.example.com
fostrain02.example.com
fostrain03.example.com
```

### Content of `file2`

```
# cat fil2
ServerIPS 171.20.20.16 171.20.20.17 171.20.20.18 171.20.20.19 171.20.20.20
ServerIPS 171.20.20.21 171.20.20.22 171.20.20.23 171.20.20.24 171.20.20.25
```

In the below playbook, its replacing the contents on two lines one is hostname as `str` and in another line replacing the ip So, i have taken the two different task 1) `Replace strings in file`  &  2) `Replace ip in file` to accomplish this calling the variable defined.

### Playbook:

```
- name: Replace string in hosts file
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    files:
      - /etc/file1
      - /etc/file2
    from_str: "fostrain01.example.com"
      to_str: "dbfoxtrain01.example.com"
     from_ip: "^(.*)171\\.20\\.20\\.18(.*)$"
       to_ip: "\\g<1>172.20.20.18\\g<2>"
  tasks:
    - name: Replace strings in file
      replace:
        path: "{{ item}}"
        regexp: "{{ from_str }}"
        replace: "{{ to_str }}"
        backup: yes
      loop: "{{ files }}"

    - name: Replace ip in file
      replace:
        path: "{{ item}}"
        regexp: "{{ from_ip }}"
        replace: "{{ to_ip }}"
        backup: yes
      loop: "{{ files }}"
```

Can we write the task as follows something where we don't really write to two different tasks, i tried but not getting how to loops through `"{{ files }}` with below approach.

```
  tasks:
    - name: Replace elements in file
      replace:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        regexp: "{{ item.From }}"
        replace: "{{ item.To }}"
        backup: yes
      loop:
        # Replace the desired string
        - { path: "{{ item }}", From: "{{ from_str }}", To: "{{ to_str }}" }
        # Replace the desired ip
        - { path: "{{ item}}", From: "{{ from_ip }}", To: "{{ to_ip}}" }
```

### What is Desired Change:

task 1) `Replace strings in file`  & task  2) `Replace ip in file` to be clubbed into One.

### Expected Results:

```
# cat file1
dbfoxtrain01.example.com  <-- Changed
fostrain02.example.com
fostrain03.example.com

# cat fil2
ServerIPS 171.20.20.16 171.20.20.17 172.20.20.18 171.20.20.19 171.20.20.20  <-- changed here ^172
ServerIPS 171.20.20.21 171.20.20.22 171.20.20.23 171.20.20.24 171.20.20.25
```

Comment: Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add expected result.

Comment: @VladimirBotka,  thanks for the comment, i will add expected results. as i mentioned in my post i have two different tasks for two different regex for two different lines which i want to club into One task. Updated the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        regexp: "{{ item.from }}"
        replace: "{{ item.to }}"
      loop:
        - path: file1
          from: 'fostrain01\.example\.com'
          to: 'dbfoxtrain01.example.com'
        - path: file2
          from: '171\.20\.20\.18'
          to: '172.20.20.18'
```

---

Example

```yaml
shell> tree .
.
├── file1
├── file1.orig
├── file2
├── file2.orig
└── test.yml

0 directories, 5 files

shell> cat file1
fostrain01.example.com
fostrain02.example.com
fostrain03.example.com

shell> cat file2
ServerIPS 171.20.20.16 171.20.20.17 171.20.20.18 171.20.20.19 171.20.20.20
ServerIPS 171.20.20.21 171.20.20.22 171.20.20.23 171.20.20.24 171.20.20.25

shell> cat test.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - replace:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        regexp: "{{ item.from }}"
        replace: "{{ item.to }}"
      loop:
        - path: file1
          from: 'fostrain01\.example\.com'
          to: 'dbfoxtrain01.example.com'
        - path: file2
          from: '171\.20\.20\.18'
          to: '172.20.20.18'

shell> ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ************************************************

TASK [replace] **************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'path': 'file1', 'from': 'fostrain01\\.example\\.com', 'to': 'dbfoxtrain01.example.com'})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'path': 'file2', 'from': '171\\.20\\.20\\.18', 'to': '172.20.20.18'})

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************
localhost: ok=1 changed=1 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0   

shell> cat file1
dbfoxtrain01.example.com
fostrain02.example.com
fostrain03.example.com

shell> cat file2
ServerIPS 171.20.20.16 171.20.20.17 172.20.20.18 171.20.20.19 171.20.20.20
ServerIPS 171.20.20.21 171.20.20.22 171.20.20.23 171.20.20.24 171.20.20.25
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  Can you please let me know how to call these `files`  as a variable in the `path` section?

Comment: I've added a **complete** example. Still the same, make your questions [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)! (and open a new one, if any).

Comment: Just raised the [new post here -->](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62875869/how-we-can-call-a-variable-in-ansible-playbook-while-using-loops)

Comment: In the meantime, consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) @VladimirBotka's answer if it helped you :)

Comment: @VladimirBotka, Thanks again for the help  