# How we can call a variable in ansible playbook while using loops

Tags: linux, ansible

I have two files where these file contains `server names` and `server IP's`, I want to change/replace some specific `server names` and `IP addressees` in both the files based on the requirement.

This is related to [This Post <--](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62869642/ansible-aclling-two-diffrent-file-variables-into-single-task-looping-through-mul) as it was asked to open a new post.

### My scenario:

In the Below example files(`file & file2`) i need to do follows..

1 - In file1 and fil2 i have to replace `fostrain01.example.com` with `dbfostrain01.example.com`.

2 - Where in another line i have to replace `171.20.20.18` with `172.20.20.18` in both the files as well.

```
# cat /etc/file1
fostrain01.example.com
fostrain02.example.com
ServerIPS 171.20.20.16 171.20.20.17 171.20.20.18 171.20.20.19 171.20.20.20

# cat /etc/fil2
fostrain01.example.com
fostrain02.example.com  
ServerIPS 171.20.20.16 171.20.20.17 171.20.20.18 171.20.20.19 171.20.20.20
```

### My Playbook:

```
---
- name: Replace file contents
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    files:
      - /etc/file1
      - /etc/file2
    from_str: "fostrain01.example.com"
    to_str: "dbfoxtrain01.example.com"
    from_ip: "^(.*)171\\.20\\.20\\.18(.*)$"
   to_ip: "\\g<1>172.20.20.18\\g<2>"
   
  tasks:
    - name: Replace elements in file
      replace:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        regexp: "{{ item.From }}"
        replace: "{{ item.To }}"
        backup: yes
      loop:
        # Replace the desired string
        - { path: "{{ item }}", From: "{{ from_str }}", To: "{{ to_str }}" }
        #  Replace the desired ip
        - { path: "{{ item }}", From: "{{ from_ip }}", To: "{{ to_ip }}" }
```

In the above playbook, i have defined the variables for each sections as you can see.

### What I'm Missing and Would Like to Know:

I am missing to understand about `How i can use or reference files variable` in the `path` section of replace module in my `playbook` above while using `loop`.

Just to clarify, i'm talking about below one..

```
    files:
      - /etc/file1
      - /etc/file2
```

I am looking this to be fitted within the approach in the above playbook, as i know the other way around of doing it.

I am sorry, if i could not make it more clear.

Comment: Where would the variable representing the file path come from? (e.g. at the playbook invocation time, from another task, from the playbook asking for the path, ...)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε,  the file path is `/etc/fil1` & `/etc/fil2`. However, the `path: "{{ item }}"` just i kept there which i'm looking for a help to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So file is a list of variable, as any list of varibales, the items are accessible via a 0-indexed key.

- So in you case, the first element of the `files` list, containing `/etc/file1` is
  accessible either via

  ```
  files.0
  ```

  Or

  ```
  files[0]
  ```
- The second, containing `/etc/file1` is accessible either via

  ```
  files.1
  ```

  Or

  ```
  files[1]
  ```
- And so on, and so forth.

---

But there is a lot of other ways to do this:

1. you could use [`product`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#product-filters) to merge your two lists
2. you could use the `loop_control` parameter [`index_var`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#tracking-progress-through-a-loop-with-index-var) to create your own index
3. you could use the [`extended`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables) parameter of `loop_control`, that provides the extended variable `ansible_loop.index0`

---

All this said, to make it a little bit more generic, if I were you, I would use the [`product`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#product-filters) filter and go with a more simpler:

```yaml
- name: Replace elements in file
  replace:
    path: "{{ item.0 }}"
    regexp: "{{ item.1.from }}"
    replace: "{{ item.1.to }}"
    backup: yes
  vars:
    paths:
      - /etc/file1
      - /etc/file2
    replaces:
      - from: "fostrain01.example.com"
        to: "dbfoxtrain01.example.com"
      - from: "^(.*)171\\.20\\.20\\.18(.*)$"
        to: "\\g<1>172.20.20.18\\g<2>"
  loop: "{{ paths | product(replaces) | list }}"
```

Because, then there is no reason to transform your list, it is already has it should for your `replace` task.
Mind that variables can be defined both at play or task level, if you need the `replaces` variable in other tasks, just bring it back up to the play level.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, So, if i understood correctly the i need to modify my code something like `{ path: "{{ files.0}}", From: "{{ from_str }}", To: "{{ to_str }}" }`  &  `{ path: "{{ files.1}}", From: "{{ from_str }}", To: "{{ to_str }}" }`  ?

Comment: This is one way, yes

Comment: One more thing what i see in your purposed solution, `- path: /etc/file1` it only changing hostname but not the `IP address` and in `- path: /etc/file2` its vice versa whereas both files needs to be changed both things.

Comment: Well, if I re-read your scenario, this is exactly what you intend to do, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i need to replace both server name and IP address in both the files but i got it now...  

Comment: Then the nicest solution would be to use two lists and group them together with what was [with_nested](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-nested-with-cartesian) and that is now a loop using the `product` filter, which I edited in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there with your solution, Just you have to use `files` variable as an index key to the file selection as nicely illustrated by @β.εηοιτ.βε in his answer section.

So, to complete your code to make it working, it should be working as follows..

```
---
- name: Replace file contents
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    files:
      - /etc/file1
      - /etc/file2
    from_str: "fostrain01.example.com"
    to_str: "dbfoxtrain01.example.com"
    from_ip: "^(.*)171\\.20\\.20\\.18(.*)$"
   to_ip: "\\g<1>172.20.20.18\\g<2>"
  
tasks:
    - name: Replace elements in file
      replace:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        regexp: "{{ item.From }}"
        replace: "{{ item.To }}"
        backup: yes
      loop:
        # Replace the desired string
        - { path: "{{ files[0] }}", From: "{{ from_str }}", To: "{{ to_str }}" }
        - { path: "{{ files[0] }}", From: "{{ from_ip }}", To: "{{ to_ip }}" } 
        #  Replace the desired ip
        - { path: "{{ files[1] }}", From: "{{ from_str }}", To: "{{ to_str }}" }
        - { path: "{{ files[1] }}", From: "{{ from_ip }}", To: "{{ to_ip }}" }
```

Comment: Karn Kumar, thanks for the answer.. yes this is correct, it working now.. after @β.εηοιτ.βε explained that, i got to know about this.  This is working nicely now 

Comment: To be honest it just feels wrong because there is simple ways to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) it with Ansible. But it does the job indeed :)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, It's depends how you accomplish your job  there is nothing wrong and right if one tries to do based on own understanding, It's simply a choice but i agree there are ways to make things simple or more simple if one knows them to implement but for a novice or learner its good to startwith :-) .. However, i just posted the answer if this is something what OP's is thinking to accomplish it his/her own way.

Comment: To be honest, i am just learning by googling and taking solutions from the SO's answers, So, today i got a ton of information which i need to go through so i can make solution simpler and cripp :-) , thank to both of you guys  

Comment: @KarnKumar well this is what I like with SO, for the quite unfrequent times I had a question, I came with it as a newbie, and ended up understanding four times more than what I thought I would. You should not adapt the technically of your answer to your audience, you should just adapt your explanation :)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, Well this is again gona to be lengthy discussion,  In a nutshell i would say we should adapt what OP want and if that's solves the whole purpose then i believe it would also reach to the prosperity, and yes of course if question seeks an explanation that should be there which could benefit the other's apprehension :-).